# Install more packages with debootstrap

Tags: system-installation, kernel, debootstrap

`debootstrap` is a tool which will install a Debian/Ubuntu base system into a subdirectory of another, already installed system.

The installation log ends like this:

```
. . . 
I: Validating xxd 2:8.1.0320-1ubuntu3
I: Validating xz-utils 5.2.4-1
I: Validating zlib1g 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu2
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: dpkg-deb
I: Extracting base-files...
```

So it seems to me that the only package `debootstrap` extracts is `base-files`, right?

Is there any way for `debootstrap` to extract/install more packages? 
Especially, I found that `debootstrap` doesn't even install linux kernel at all. Can I somehow let `debootstrap` to install linux kernel as well?

Comment: `sudo chroot <deboostrap-directory>` followed by the commands you want to run (e.g., apt) might be more "ergonomic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't install kernel but have found [this](https://stafwag.github.io/blog/blog/2019/04/22/building-your-own-docker-images_part1/)

In the link The code bit `--include=iputils-ping` is an example of how to add package but you after install the machine in a folder you like, you can `chroot` in that folder add all apt repo you like and give `apt update && apt upgrade` or `apt install packXXX`

To my study I have do this:
`$ mkdir -p sviluppo/studio/progetti/docker/immagini/ubuntu19.10`
`$ cd sviluppo/studio/progetti/docker/immagini/ubuntu19.10`
**Importan do not forget to do a `cd` on the future chroot folder like mine above**

`$ sudo apt policy debootstrap`

> debootstrap:   Installato: 1.0.116ubuntu1.1   Candidato: 
>   1.0.116ubuntu1.1   Tabella versione:  *** 1.0.116ubuntu1.1 500
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main i386 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>        1.0.116ubuntu1 500
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages

Then I have installed ubuntu 19.10 on my folder:
`$ sudo debootstrap --verbose eoan ./`
`$ sudo vim ./etc/apt/sources.list`
and change it to:

```bsh
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner

# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-proposed main restricted universe multiverse #Non per esseri umani durante la fase di sviluppo del rilascio eoan
```

Then

```bsh
# sudo chroot /home/leonardo/sviluppo/studio/progetti/docker/immagini/ubuntu19.10
# sudo apt update
# sudo apt list --upgradable
```

> file/eoan-updates,eoan-security 1:5.37-5ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable
>   from: 1:5.37-5] libfribidi0/eoan-updates,eoan-security
>   1.0.5-3.1ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.5-3.1] libmagic-mgc/eoan-updates,eoan-security 1:5.37-5ubuntu0.1 amd64
>   [upgradable from: 1:5.37-5] libmagic1/eoan-updates,eoan-security
>   1:5.37-5ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:5.37-5]

```bsh
# sudo apt upgrade
# exit
```

Regards,
Leonardo